# Sagt ihr „Reue für“?

Tags: preposition

Ich lese hier gerade einen Satz, der mir (selbst für einen Fantasyroman) sehr falsch vorkommt.

> Die Reue für jenen schwarzen Tag im vergangenen Jahr, jenen dunkelsten Tag in Sygnas unzweifelhaft düsterer Geschichte, schmeckte metallen wie das Blut in seiner Kehle,...

Für mich ist die natürliche Präposition mit „Reue“ entweder „über“, oder veraltend „ob“.

Entspricht „Reue für“ eurem muttersprachlichen Gefühl?
Gibt es dafür Beispiele aus der älteren Literatur?
Breitet sich die Verwendung evtl. aus?

Comment: Auch für mich klingt _Reue für_ nicht richtig. Abgesehen davon müsste es _metallisch_ (wie Metall) anstatt _metallen_ (aus Metall bestehend) heißen.

Comment: Die Konstruktion mit dem Nomen Reue klingt gestelzt. Liegt aber vielleicht am Bild: Reue schmeckt wie Blut. Verwendet man Reue überhaupt so? Oder eher mit dem Verb empfinden? Er empfand Reue, als er daran dachte, ein Gefühl, beinahe wie der metallische Geschmack von Blut. Ist aber alles nicht ideal.

Comment: Das ist offenbar ein Buch, das einen Lektor nicht mal aus der Ferne gesehen hat. Die Ausdrucksweise schmeckt hölzern wie der Stuhl unter meinem Wertesten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Das **Deutsche Wörterbuch** der **Grimms** schreibt:

> "reue mit dem gen. der sache, um, an, auf etwas; in neuerer sprache gewöhnlich reue über etwas." (reue bis reuemeer (Bd. 14, Sp. 830 bis 836)

Leider sind die angeführten Beispiele alle sehr alt. Die Entstehungszeit (Publikation?) des Artikels zu 'Reue' liegt nach den auffindbaren Angaben um 1890. Dort werden als weitere Verbindungsmöglichkeiten genannt: *Reue **an***, *Reue **um***.

In der Beispielsammlung des **DWDS** finden sich 246 Belege mit "*Reue über*" und 56 zu "*Reue für*". Dazu zählen jedoch auch (seltenere) Fälle wie "*das Gericht hielt seine Reue für glaubhaft*", für die "*Reue über*" konnte ich kein analoges Beispiel finden.

**Google Ngram Viewer** zeigt über den gesamten Berichtszeitraum ein deutliches Überwiegen von "*Reue über*", allerdings nimmt die "*Reue für*" in den letzten Jahren proportional relativ stark zu. Dabei ist jedoch unklar, wie viele abweichende Fälle nach dem Muster "*hält seine Reue für gespielt*" sich darin verbergen:
https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Reue+f%C3%BCr%2C+Reue+%C3%BCber&year_start=1800&year_end=2018&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CReue%20f%C3%BCr%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CReue%20%C3%BCber%3B%2Cc0

Insgesamt wird "*Reue über*" anzahlmäßig deutlich bevorzugt, aber die Fälle von "*Reue für*" sind derart häufig, dass sie nicht als außerordentlich ungewöhnlich angesehen werden können. Damit bestätigt sich - zu meiner Überraschung - die Aussage von Hubert Schölnast - ich selbst hätte an die "*Reue für*" einige Fragezeichen geheftet.

Eine weitere Anschlussmöglichkeit wäre "*Reue angesichts*".

Comment: Ja. Reue um kann ich mir auch vorstellen.

Answer (score 7):

Prinzipiell gilt, das Sprache die Aufgabe hat, Ideen von einem Sender zu einem Empfänger zu transportieren. Wenn im Kopf des Empfängers die Ideen entstehen, die im Kopf des Senders vorhanden waren, hat die Sprache ihren Zweck erfüllt.

Aus diesem grundlegenden Zweck heraus haben sich bestimmte Gepflogenheiten entwickelt, nämlich ein Wortschatz und eine Grammatik. Beide zusammen bilden im Wesentlichen eine Sprache. Der Wortschatz stellt Begriffe bereit, die mit bestimmten Bedeutungen verknüpft sind, und die Grammatik stellt bedeutungstragende Beziehungen zwischen den Wörtern her.

Eine Sprache kann dann ihren Zweck erfüllen, wenn Sender und Empfänger einen halbwegs übereinstimmenden Wortschatz verwenden, und wenn auch über die Grammatik zumindest eine grobe Einigkeit besteht. Je besser die Übereinstimmungen sind, desto weniger Missverständnisse gibt es.

Beides (sowohl Wortschatz als auch Grammatik) kann man normen, bzw. standardisieren. Das Ergebnis sind Nachschlagewerke, in denen diese Standards festgehalten werden, nämlich Wörterbücher bzw. Lexika für den Wortschatz und Grammatikbücher. Natürlich spielt bei solchen Nachschlagewerken auch noch die Orthografie eine wichtige Rolle, die aber ein ausschließliches Ergebnis der Verschriftlichung der Sprache ist. Eine Sprache an sich braucht aber nicht zwingend eine Schrift, daher gehe ich hier auf die Rechtschreibung nicht näher ein.

Die so entstandenen Standards sind bei lebenden Sprachen immer unvollständig und immer veraltet. Wegen des stetigen Wandels lebender Sprachen ist es nicht möglich, den Wortschatz vollständig zu erfassen, und es ist auch nicht möglich, ein vollständiges Abbild der zu einem bestimmten Zeitpunkt geltenden Grammatik herzustellen. Gute Annäherungen an den Ist-Stand sind natürlich möglich, aber es wird bei Spezialfällen immer Lücken geben.

Gerade die Präpositionen sind ein sehr unübersichtliches Feld, und wenn Präpositionen von Nomen abhängen, schweigen sich die meisten Grammatikbücher ohnehin aus.

Eine Ausnahme ist die Website [Nomen mit Präpositionen](http://yildiz.biz/nomen-mit-praepositionen). Dort steht über die Reue:

> Die **Reue:** über + Akkusativ
>   Er empfand tiefe Reue über seine Taten.

Weil sonst keine anderen Präpositionen angeboten werden, liegt der Schluss nahe, dass *»Reue für«* falsch sein könnte. Aber eine Zeile über der Reue steht auf dieser Seite:

> Die **Rettung:** vor + Dativ
>   Die Rettung vor den Fluten geschah in letzter Sekunde.

Dieses Beispiel ist zwar korrekt, aber man kann jemanden auch **aus** den Fluten retten:

> Die Rettung **aus** den Fluten erfolgte durch den Einsatz eines Hubschraubers.

*»Rettung + aus + Dativ«* steht aber nicht auf der verlinkten Seite. Sie ist daher erwiesenermaßen unvollständig, und das bedeutet, dass die Kombination *»Reue + für + Akkusativ«* nicht kategorisch ausgeschlossen werden kann.

Andere Quellen zu diesem Problem habe ich leider nicht gefunden. Insbesondere habe ich nichts gefunden, dass den eindeutigen Schluss zuließe, *»Reue + für + Akkusativ«* wäre falsch.

Ich interpretiere diesen Zustand so, dass man *»Reue«* zwar meist mit der Präposition *»über«* verwendet, dass aber auch andere Präpositionen, wie z.B. *»für«* möglich sind.

Der Zweck des zitierten Satzes ist es jedenfalls beim Leser ein bestimmtes Verständnis der Situation hervorzurufen, und diesen Zweck kann dieser Satz durchaus erfüllen. Ich konnte auch keinen Grammatikstandard finden, der diesen Satz klar als falsch ausweisen würde. Daher komme ich zu dem Schluss:

**Die Präposition ist ungewöhnlich, aber nicht falsch.**

Da der Autor einen poetischen Stil verwendet (*»Die Reue ... schmeckt metallen«*), war es vielleicht sogar seine Absicht, eine ungewöhnliche Präposition zu verwenden. Immerhin hat er auch ein ungewöhnliches Adjektiv (*metallen* statt *metallisch*) verwendet, das auch nicht wirklich falsch, sondern nur ungewöhnlich ist.

(Darüber hinaus kann ein immaterielles Gefühle wie die Reue auf der Zunge und in der Nase keine chemischen Rezeptoren reizen, und daher auch nicht nach etwas schmecken. Hier liegt ganz klar eine Metapher vor, was ein weiterer Hinweis auf die Absicht des Autors ist, einen poetischen Stil an den Tag zu legen, über dessen Qualität sich sicherlich trefflich streiten ließe.)

Comment: Schon mal von Synästhesie oder Psychosomatik gehört? Man kann auch einen fiesen Geschmack im Mund haben ohne dass die Geschmacksrezeptoren beansprucht werden. Das ist nicht nur poetische Freiheit.

Comment: Der gegenständliche Satz sollte, wie ich glaube, wohl kaum die Empfindungen eines Synästheten wahrheitsgetreu wiedergeben, sondern er soll wohl eher auf poetische um metaphernreiche Weise ein Gefühl für die Situation hervorrufen.

Comment: Die populärsten Beispiele, wie Gefühle mit Geschmack verbunden sein können, sind wohl Bitterkeit und Süße, aber auch sauer oder scharf sein stellen Verbindungen von Geschmack und Gefühl her. Die Argumentation, dass eine fehlende Präposition nicht deren Falschheit belegt, betrachte ich dagegen als bravourös geführt. Das Normen und standardisieren sehe ich aber nicht ganz akkurat dargestellt. Die Sprachwissenschaft versteht sich m.W. mehr als sammelnde und kategorisierende Disziplin, die nur einordnet, was sie vorfindet.

Comment: Erst später kam mir die Erinnerung, dass Blut (z.B. beim Nasenbluten) ja tatsächlich nach Eisen riecht und schmeckt. Auch wenn die Metapher vom 'metallenen Geschmack' etwas pompös formuliert erscheinen mag, so ist sie zumindest von der Sache her zutreffend.

Answer (score 5):

Ich meine auch, dass »Reue für« nur ungewöhnlich, aber nicht falsch ist. Begründen würde ich es so:

Reue lässt sich als Rechnung verstehen, die man für persönliches Fehlverhalten zahlt. Und da wir »Rechnung für« verwenden, spricht nichts dagegen, das auch bei der Reue zu tun.